# SQL Server behind a Web API that returns a csv file. In VS Code how can I automate passing the current open sql file to this API?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

We have a reporting engine that is running on SQL Server. We have a UI to develop those queries but when dealing with more complex queries it is just easier to use Visual Studio Code.

I can't connect directly to SQL Server but there is an API that I can pass a SQL query to and it would return a link to an s3 bucket containing a `.csv` of the resulting data.

I can write a Python script to do all of that. What I'd like to be able to have is something like a "Run" button that will run that script and then display the tabular results all within VS Code. As an additional bonus the SQL functionality is limited in this reporting engine (users are prevented from running things like "select *") and it would be nice to be able to highlight when I use some functionality that is being prevented.

**TLDR;** Can I create an extension or task that will allow me to click the Run button (or something) that will run a script on an open SQL file?

I looked into creating a task and assigning it to the run button but I didn't see how to display the data and wasn't sure if there was a simpler way to go about this.

Comment: Yes, you can create extensions in Visual Studio Code, why not follow one of their tutorials to do so, this question is way too broad for stackoverflow